# UniCurses pdcurses.dll Error

Tags: python, pdcurses, unicurses

When trying to import the UniCurses package, I receive the error "UniCurses initialization error - pdcurses.dll not found."

I have downloaded the pdcurses distributions (specifically pdc34dllw.zip) and extracted the files to:

- *\Python\Lib\site-packages   (Where unicurses.py is located)
- *\Python\Lib\site-packages\unicurses
- *\Python

None of these have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To allow import, `pdcurses.dll` needs to be located in the python folder, for example `C:\python36`. To run a python script which imports and executes unicurses modules, the `pdcurses.dll` needs to be located in the same folder as the python script you are executing, so it needs to be located in 2 places.

Comment: + in case of terminal  - make sure to add the pdcurses.dll to the directory from which you are running python through terminal